# Scale a Bitmap into an already Existing Bitmap

Tags: android, optimization, bitmap

Is there a way to directly scale a bitmap (bigBmp) into another bitmap (smallBmp) whithout creating a new one?

This creates a new one:

```
Bitmap smallBmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bigBmp, 20, 20, false);
```

I need to scale it always to the same size so I'd rather create smallBmp in advance (with size 20x20) and reuse this one every time.

I know, creating a 20x20 bitmap is probably not worth the optimization but it's inside a heavy loop where I just don't want any allocations.

Comment: Bitmap recycling is a complex area in android environment. There are different methods according to android versions which your applicaiton supports. You can read these android documentation : http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/manage-memory.html

Comment: Maybe you should create thumbnail and save to another directory. While loading check it and if exist load it or if not exist create thumbnail